# Translating WP query into to SQL query

Tags: wp-query, database, sql

I have very complex wp query and I want to use sql query instead of this. Is there any way to translate wp query to sql query.
I am thinking that I will have a better control over sql query as the wp query is not fulfilling my requirements.

Comment: You can use $wpdb->prepare to run your custom SQL Query. Please check these links:
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wpdb/prepare/  &   https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb

Comment: Okay but is there any way to translate existing wp query to sql query automatically ?

Comment: What's the context behind translating it into SQL? What are the requirements you're needing to add? `WP_Query` might be able to fulfill them if you share what they are via filters or options you might be unaware of. It could even be that the way your storing things could be improved to be faster and easier to query. Note that by using raw SQL you give up any benefits of WP Cache, object caching, and caching plugins

Comment: Technically there is no way to do that. At the very least you are dealing with two tables viz `_posts and _postmeta`. You can try out creating a local clone of the site(or the database if you just want to play with sql queries and form one to your liking) and test them out in a client like phpmyadmin.

Comment: Posting your query here might be helpful and as @TomJNowell mentioned you give up on significant benefits by using direct sql statement.

Comment: @FahamShaikh Yes agreed and I am displaying products and have some filters on this page and I have wp query to get filtered results but this wp query is not working for variations stock as I am dealing with WooCommerce products. My actual problem is explain here
https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/340236/wordpress-query-through-products-variation-stock

Comment: @TomJNowell if you could input on above thread that would be great. Thank you for your time.

Comment: @wplearner in all honesty that other question is a WooCommerce question, and 3rd party plugins are offtopic here. As for automatically converting `WP_Query` into SQL, just run the `WP_Query` and log the actual query that was ran. Most debug plugins will show you that information, as will SQL logs. Also, what you're trying to do looks like a very expensive/slow query to run